# Описания ошибок

Tags: android, logcat

Где хранятся все описания ошибок выводимые в LogCat, то есть то, что выводится при ошибках? Распределены ли встроенные сообщения по коду (что и выяснилось) или помещены в файл ресурсов на подобие res/values/strings.xml.

Comment: Видимо, в компиляторе

Comment: В документации?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю, видимо, ошибки, они же всякого рода исключения распределены в коде Android Studio относительно равномерно, а потому выводятся в LogCat исходя из текущего разрабатываемого кода по мере затрагиваемых разработчиком классов, методов, переменных и так далее.

Comment: Да, исключения выбрасываются тогда, когда в этом есть необходимость (произошла соответствующая исключительная ситуация). Что именно вызывает у вас сомнения или требует уточнений?